# Get the text of a message known the message identifier (chat_id, message_id) with telepot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telepot

I want to find a message and get his text.
I know that if i have the message object I only have to do:

```
msg["text"]
```

But I don't have it, I have a message identifier like this:

```
(chat_id, message_id)
```

Obtained via:

```
telepot.origin_identifier(callback_query)
```

So I aslo have the `callback_query` object.

Had these information how can I get the text of the message that sent me these callback query?

Comment: Could it be in `msg["data"]`? (https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#telepot.glance)

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of the message who sent the callback query we have to do:

```
callback_query["message"]["text"]
```